# PHP - not operator, any other aliases?

Tags: php, operators, logical-operators

`if(!($whatever && what()) do_stuff...`

Can this be replaced with something more intuitive like:

`if(not($whatever && what()) do_stuff...`

?

Comment: It is already intuitive enough. `!` operator is known by any developer of almost any programming language.

Comment: Instead of coming up with something more intuitive *for you*, you could also just get used to the `!`, since that is pretty intuitive for *everybody else*. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function not($OriginalCheck)
{
    return !$OriginalCheck;
}

function is($OriginalCheck)
{
    return !!$OriginalCheck;
}
```

should do exactly that :)

There are several ways to write checks:

- `if(!($whatever && what()) do_stuff...`
- `if(!$whatever || !what()) do_stuff...`
- `if(($whatever && what()) === false) do_stuff...`
- `if((!$whatever || !what()) === true) do_stuff...`
- `if($whatever === false || what() === false) === true) do_stuff...`

all these ways are intuitive and known through out the programming world.

Comment: not worth writing a custom function :) if there's no standard php function/operator for that I'll just use `!`

Comment: @Kamil, Thanks, @Alexandra - Im just providing what the op wanted, although your correct.

Comment: there should be `||` in the last condition

Answer (score 2):

No it can't. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php for the language reference about logical operators, and navigate to find other aliases.

Note however that the precedence of `&&` and `||` is not the same as `and` and `or`.

Comment: 1. There is no alias for `!` (which is what was asked for). 2. If you refer to `and` and `or`, they have different precedence and should be handled carefully: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my answer. My mind skipped when I saw and/or in addition to && and ||. The advice to look at the language reference still holds, though

Answer (score 1):

One option is to make the boolean expression more explicit:

```
if(($whatever && what()) == false) // do_stuff...
```

Or alternatively, by implementing a custom `not()`:

```
function not($expr) {
    return $expr == false;
}

if(not($whatever && what())) // do_stuff...
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I don't like the `!` operator as well. Although it was understood by every developers but it took me a bit of time every time I read the code. So I prefer do not use the `!` operator. But it depends on also.

For php built-in function, I created almost the helper functions for not operator.

https://github.com/vuvanly/not-operators-helpers

Answer (score 0):

There is no alternative `!`, but it could be written **less** intuitive:

```
if ($whatever - 1) {
}
```

Should the question cause be that `!` is *too easy to overlook*, but `not` more visible; then another alternative notation would be:

```
if (!!! $whatever) {
```

If this still looks to simple, just use:

```
if (~$whatever & 1) {
```

Binary operations always look professional ;)

Comment: @nikic: Made it because it doesn't really answer the question; it's the opposite of the intent. And maybe someone else might contribute something silly.

Comment: @mario: Wouldn't the last example negate the first part only?

Comment: @nikic: true, needs moar braces. (Maybe that was another subconscious reason for OP to ask for `not` which would likely have a weaker precedence like `and` and `or`)

Comment: @Alexandra: It inverts all bits of an integer ;)